# Can't connect to scanner

Tags: release-hera

I have a fresh install of elementary os 5.1 hera. The only thing I am stuck with is trying to get this os to work with my Samsung C480W printer + scanner. The printer works fine but the scanner simply won't connect over a LAN. I have already installed the recommended samsung uld driver and created the required soft links for libsane.so. The same scanner works fine with a laptop running linux mint 19.2 (also based on Ubuntu 18.04 and having the same uld drivers). The only errors I can see are in /var/log/syslog which seem to suggest the scanner details cannot be found in a file called models.dat.

Has anybody faced and solved a similar problem on elementary? Any help in getting this to work will be quite appreciated.

Regards

Dipak Jha

Comment: just wanted to let you know that your journey helped me a lot! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for trying to help. I finally found a solution here:

https://linux.tutorialforbeginners.net/2018/10/08/samsung-printer-driver-ubuntu-18-04-installation-guide/

I followed these instructions step by step and now have a system that seamless connects to the C48 series Samsung scanner and correctly scans documents. The error about details not being found in models.dat turns out to be a red herring since I can still see the warnings in syslog despite the system happily scanning away.

But must say this has been a rather painful journey with a massive amount of effort having been invested in solving a seemingly simple issue.

Regards

Dipak Jha

Answer (score 1):

I have found some solutions here: 
[missing models.dat file](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hplip/+bug/1744340)

One gyu suggested to create a symbolic links with the ls -l command. I do not have this problem with my Canon MG 2550S, however you can use find or locate to find the dat file and make a symbolic link.